# Comparing equal types in a definition

Tags: lean

I'm fairly new to Lean, so apologies if this is obvious. I'm trying to learn Lean and category theory, by doing some category theory exercises in Lean. I have these definitions for arrows and categories:

```
variable {α : Type u}

inductive Arrow : α → α → Type u
  | Id (x : α) : Arrow x x
  | Comp (g : Arrow b c) (f : Arrow a b) : Arrow a c

notation a " -→ " b => Arrow a b
notation a " ∘ " b => Arrow.Comp a b

structure Category :=
  (assoc {a b c d : α} : ∀ (f : a -→ b) (g : b -→ c) (k : c -→ d),
    (k ∘ (g ∘ f)) = ((k ∘ g) ∘ f))
  (unitl {a b : α} : ∀ (f : a -→ b), ((Arrow.Id b) ∘ f) = f)
  (unitr {a b : α} : ∀ (f : a -→ b), (f ∘ (Arrow.Id a)) = f)
```

This all compiles fine, so I try to define a discrete category as follows:

```
def IsDiscrete :=
  ∀ (x y : α) (f : Arrow x y), x = y ∧ f = Arrow.Id x
```

The intent is to express "all arrows are identity arrows", but the compiler complains that f has type "Arrow x y", not "Arrow x x". Of course, the whole point is that if arrow f exists, then x = y, so the comparison between f and Id x is sensible. How do I express this in Lean?

Alternatively, is there a better way to express arrows and/or categories in Lean? If so, why is that way better?

Comment: Equality of objects is not a very well-behaved notion in category theory. Your definition of  discrete category would not be stable under equivalence of categories. The morally equivalent way would be to say that any two objects either have no morphisms between them, or a unique isomorphism. In other words: if you have two arrows `f g : x ⟶ y` then `f = g`. I think this is the mathematically correct notion, and it is also straightforward to express in Lean.

Comment: Perhaps try `x = y ∧ HEq f (Arrow.Id x)`

Comment: @jmc Wouldn't this permit categories with a unique arrow `x ⟶ y`, even if x and y are distinct? Is the key that you're demanding such an arrow be an isomorphism, so the objects are sort of "equal" in some sense?
@AtnNn That did the trick, at least in the "how to use Lean" sense. Would you mind expanding that to an answer we could accept, even if it's not the right way to model categories?

Comment: @DavidLegg yes. jmc's point is concepts of category theory which are not invariant under equivalence are "evil" in the sense that they do not obey the principle of equivalence http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/principle%20of%20equivalence . Another way of doing it would be demanding that `Arrow x y` was always a subsingleton, and that if if you have a term of type `Arrow x y` then you can deduce that x = y. Note that equality of objects is also evil in category theory.